# How do I log data from a live website using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

Hello I am trying to use beautiful soup and requests to log the data coming from an anemometer which updates live every second. The link to this website here:

`http://88.97.23.70:81/`

The piece of data I want to scrape is highlighted in purple in the image :

[image: attached]

from inspection of the html in my browser.

I have written the code bellow in to try to print out the data however when I run the code it prints: `None`. I think this means that the soup object doesnt infact contain the whole html page? Upon printing `soup.prettify()` I cannot find the same `id=js-2-text` I find when inspecting the html in my browser. If anyone has any ideas why this might be or how to fix it I would be most grateful.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

wind_url='http://88.97.23.70:81/'
   
r = requests.get(wind_url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
           
print(soup.find(id='js-2-text'))
```

All the best,
Brendan

Comment: I guess that this part is inserted into the page dynamically with JavaScript. If so, you need something like Selenium to extract the data or you can try to find out how the data is dynamically loaded (and from where).

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external URL, so beautifulsoup doesn't need it. You can try to use API URL the page is connecting to:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = "http://88.97.23.70:81/cgi-bin/CGI_GetMeasurement.cgi"
data = {"input_id": "1"}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(api_url, data=data).content, "html.parser")
_, direction, metres_per_second, *_ = soup.csv.text.split(",")

knots = float(metres_per_second) * 1.9438445

print(direction, metres_per_second, knots)
```

Prints:

```
210 006.58 12.79049681
```

Comment: Hi thats worked beautifully for me in terms of getting the information out a handful of times however when i try to run this within a loop i end up getting this error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='88.97.23.70', port=81): Max retries exceeded with url. Presumably because i am sending too many requests from my ip address. Typically i might try to add in a sleep period of about 5seconds between requests to avoid overloading the server but as this data refreshes at a rate of 1 hz this isnt viable.. Is there a way around this?